# How to Make UITableViewSections respond to a click to bring up another view controller, using NSFetchedResultsController and Core Data

Tags: ios, button, core-data, tableview, sections

I have a fairly simple but working app right now; it's my first app and I'm working through the processes.

There are 4 Tab Bars with Table View controllers with a plus button on the top right. The user clicks that button and is presented modally with a Modal View Controller. They are asked to fill in 4 sets of information in text fields and when they click save, it saves it to the Core Data database, dismisses the View and adds that information to the Table Views. Let's call the items that the user fills in:

- Name
- Title
- Date
- Amount

The 4 tab bars are just different views of the same information. For example, Tab Bar 1 has Date as the section header and name, Amount and Title in each row. Nice and easy.

Tab Bar 2 has Name in the section title with Date, Amount and Title in the row. Tab Bar 3 has Title in the section title, etc. You get the idea.

Rather than just doing this though, in Tab 2, 3 and 4, I want to actually JUST have the section headers as buttons of some form that when clicked, takes a user to that particular entry. For example, in Tab Bar 2, I have the name as the section - I want to remove the rows associated with that entry and have just sections (or buttons) with the Names; I click on a name and it takes me to another view controller which will contain all of the Title, Amount, Dates, information, etc.

My question is, what's the best way to go about this approach of removing the rows in the sections and somehow making the sections clickable buttons?

My thinking is rather than use tableViews, use buttons, etc, but is there an elegant way to do this with having already implemented NSFetchedResultsController for each of the table views in each of the Tab Bars.

Any assistance would be massively appreciated.

Thanks,

EDIT:

I have just thought of a possible way to achieve this and it would be great if anyone could validate my thoughts. Rather than create a button, have a UICollectionView in the Tab 2, 3 and 4 providing the attributes from Core Data. So the UICollectionView for tab 2 can assign the NAME attribute to the label inside the Cell and then it can act like a cell and be clicked on. This sounds like the most feasible way to achieve this.